# char** to char*[] in C

Tags: c, pointers

Is it possible to convert a `char**` to `char*[]` (I have the size of the char** variable)

For example:

```
int    size           = 4;
char **str            = an_init_function ();
char  *new_str[size]  = conversion       (str)
```

Comment: Firstly, You can't initialize the variable-sized object `new_str[size]`.

Comment: And a function can't return an array type.

Comment: @Matputer C99 introduces support for VLA (variable-length arrays).

Comment: Assuming that `an_init_function` returns a pointer to four pointers, then you would need to copy each pointer individually to `new_str`.

Comment: As user3386109 said. Additionally there is no need to define `new_str` as `str` behaves identically as far as the syntax is concerned.

Comment: In the context of a function's parameter list a `char **` is the same as a `char *[]`.